# Find nearest date in string array

Tags: ios, objective-c, optimization, nsarray

So, I've got an sorted `NSArray` that contains `NSString` object (downloaded from a server), with the format: `yyyy-MM-dd`.

It's pretty much like this:

```
NSArray <NSString *> *dates = @[@"2017-06-25",
                                @"2017-06-26",
                                @"2017-06-27",
                                @"2017-06-28",
                                @"2017-06-30",
                                @"2017-07-01",
                                @"2017-07-02",
                                @"2017-07-03"];
```

So, today is 2017-06-29, and it's not in the array. How do I get the next nearest one? In this sample is `06-30`, but it might be 07-01 if `06-30` doesn't exist...

**Update**

So people are asking me about what I've attempted to do. So it's like this (not very effective, but work)

1. Find if today is in the array (if yes, return)
2. Loop dates:

   2.1 Convert `dateString` to `date`

   2.2 Compare if `date` is greater than `today` => return if YES
3. If not found in step#2, return last object in dates array.

Actual code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSUInteger index = [dates indexOfObject:[formatter stringFromDate:today]];

// Step 1
if (index == NSNotFound) {

    // Step 2: Loop converted
    NSInteger i = 0;
    for (NSString *date in dates) {

        // Step2.1: find the next nearest date's index
        NSDate *convertedDate = [formmater dateFromString:date];

        // Step2.2: Compare
        if ([convertedDate intervalSinceDate:today] > 0) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }

        i++;
    }

    // Step 3: Still not found, index = last index
    if (index == NSNotFound) index = i-1;
}

return dates[index];
```

This doesn't look so good because I might reload the dates array pretty much. Can I have a better solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add your code. A simple approach would be to loop through the array and calculate the time between the 2 dates. Store the date with the smallest difference. Of course, if you know the list is pre-sorted then you can make obvious optimisations (ignore any dates before the date being checked against and ignore any dates except the one with the smallest difference after the date being checked against).

Comment: `NSDateFormatter` at least to translate the dates into a `NSDate`. Then, what are you looking for exactly ? Closest in the future? Closest in the past? Closest whatever? What are your attempts?

Comment: @RoboticCat I don't have any idea about how to find this. In my code, I just check if today is found. The array is sorted. Do you think I'll have to converted the whole array to `NSDate`, add today, sort again then find the nearest one?

Comment: @Larme asked to find next nearest, which means in the future

Comment: @Eddie define "better" answer. Just because it loops twice so somehow in your view its "slower". Dude, get some metrics down for your code. Look at memory and time usage and then comeback and say why your solution or some other is worse. The answer listed below is fine and does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the simplest solution for your problem. **Updated solution based on sorting order!**

We can use NSPredicate Block to solve.

```
    static NSDateFormatter* formatter = nil;
    static NSDate* today = nil;


    // return an NSDate for a string given in yyyy-MM-dd
    - (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string {
        if (formatter == nil) {
            formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
            formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
        }
        return [formatter dateFromString:string];
    }

    // Helps to return today date.
    -(NSDate*) getTodayDate {
        if (today == nil) {
            today = [NSDate date];
        }
        return today;
    }

            // Helps to find nearest date from Array using Predicate
    -(NSString*)findNearestDate:(NSArray*)dateArray {
        today = nil;


        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSString *dateString, NSDictionary *bind){
            // this is the important part, lets get things in NSDate form so we can use them.
            NSDate *dob = [self dateFromString:dateString];
            NSComparisonResult result = [[self getTodayDate] compare:dob];
            if (result == NSOrderedSame || result == NSOrderedAscending) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }];


        // Apply the predicate block.
        NSArray *futureDates = [dateArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        if ([futureDates count] > 0) {
            // Sort the Array.
            futureDates = [futureDates sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
            return [futureDates objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        return nil;
    }

    NSArray <NSString *> *dates = @[@"2017-06-25",
                                    @"2017-06-26",
                                    @"2017-06-27",
                                    @"2017-06-28",
                                    @"2017-06-30",
                                    @"2017-07-01",
                                    @"2017-07-02",
                                    @"2017-07-03"];

    NSLog(@"Nearest Date: %@", [self findNearestDate:dates]);
```

Answer: Nearest Date: 2017-06-30

Comment: why use compare when you can get dateInterval and compare with 0?

Comment: I am using NSComparisonResult in Predicate. It will help us to find the Order.

Comment: I think we can use the date comparison like this and work pretty much the same: `return [[self getDateToday] intervalSinceDate:dob] >= 0;` Also, wouldn't it be better if we use `[dateArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:]` block predicate?

Comment: Yeah >= is equal to result == NSOrderedSame || result == NSOrderedAscending.

Comment: Please find the updated answer which you will help you for sorted dates.

Answer (score 3):

Your algorithm is not bad, though your code doesn't appear to implement it (no sort?). If you'd like to improve it consider this:

First there is probably little point in doing a first scan to check for an exact match - that is potentially a linear search (implemented by `indexOfObject:`) through an unordered array, and if it fails you have to scan again for a close match, just do them at the same time.

Second there is no advantage in sorting, which is at best O(NlogN), as a linear search, O(N), will find you the answer you need.

Here is a sketch:

1. Convert the date you are searching for from `NSString` to `NSDate`, call it, say, `target`
2. Set `bestMatch`, an `NSString` to `nil`. Set `bestDelta`, an `NSTimeInterval`, to the maximum possible value `DBL_MAX`.
3. Iterate over your `dates` array:

   3.1. Convert the string date to an `NSDate`, say `date`

   3.2. Set `delta` to the difference between `date` and `target`

   3.3. If `delta` is zero you have an exact match, return it

   3.4. If `delta` is better than `bestDelta`, update `bestDelta` and `bestMatch`
4. After iteration `bestMatch` is the best match or `nil` if there wasn't one.

That is a single iteration, O(N), early return on exact match.

HTH

Comment: Check the updated algorithm. Looks like mine is the same as yours. I've updated it to match my code below.

Comment: You are still making two passes over the array. You've now stated the array is sorted so the algorithm above can be trivially improved to terminate once a date past the target one is found. So the two algorithms are not the same, but the differences might in practice be minimal.

Comment: So, you mean I should remove `indexOfObject:` and just perform loop?

Comment: See step 3.3 in the answer. And with your introduced pre-condition that the array is sorted step 3.4 no longer requires to keep track of the best delta, the 1st +ve delta is the best, and that also means the 2 steps can be trivially combined... Furthermore the array being sorted allows the linear iteration to be replaced by a *binary search*, reducing the complexity to O(logN) - but such a change would only be worth it the array is large and probably overkill in your situation, though I now see you've chosen a more complex solution anyway so maybe not! Hope this exploration has been useful.

Comment: I don't think that's a much more complex solution, if the other guy just changed the predicate with `indexOfObjectPassingTest:`. It'd be much better, I think :| anw, thanks for you help! Really appreciated. Confirmed my algorithm anw.

Comment: Depends on your definition of complex ;-) One uses a predicate (memory allocation), a block (and more), creates a secondary array (even more), etc.; the other two a simple loop with early exit. Anyway, you've appreciated the many answers and discussion, so that's good! Keep an inquiring mind, it will serve you well.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Input

So you have an array of `NSString` like this

```
// input
NSArray<NSString *> * words = @[@"2017-06-25",
                                @"2017-06-26",
                                @"2017-06-27",
                                @"2017-06-28",
                                @"2017-06-30",
                                @"2017-07-01",
                                 @"2017-07-02",
                                 @"2017-07-03"];
```

### 2. Converting the array of `NSString` into an array of `NSDate`

First of all you need to convert the each input string into an NSDate

```
NSMutableArray<NSDate *> * dates = [NSMutableArray new];
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
for (NSString * word in words) {
    [dates addObject:[dateFormatter dateFromString:word]];
}
```

### 3. Finding the `nearestDate`

Now you can find the nearest date

```
NSDate * nearestDate = nil;
NSTimeInterval deltaForNearesttDate = 0;
NSDate * now = [NSDate new];
for (NSDate * date in dates) {
    NSTimeInterval delta = fabs([date timeIntervalSinceDate:now]);
    if (nearestDate == nil || (delta < deltaForNearesttDate)) {
        deltaForNearesttDate = delta;
        nearestDate = date;
    }
}
```

### 4. Conclusion

The result is into the `nearestDate` variable so

```
NSLog(@"%@", nearestDate);
```

> Wed Jun 28 00:00:00 2017

Comment: this looks pretty much worse than my solution :| you got to loop twice to find, while mine's only once (maybe not even fully loop)

Comment: @Eddie You asked `How do I get the next nearest one?`. Then you updated your question with your own code. So what are you asking exactly? A solution with less loops than yours?

Comment: I'm sorry, people were asking for my code so I added them. Yes, your answer did the job. But can you think of another one better than mine? I was asking for a good solution for the problem

Comment: @Eddie: I think that `indexOfObject:` does a loop too (it iterates until it find the object). So you do in fact 2 loops too.